# Quick Test for Two XML Documents

Tags: xml, java-8, xml-parsing

Say I have two XML documents: One generated from BaseX and one from a marshalling process in JAXB.

I would like to test the equality of both of them for validation purposes.

If they are identical in both structure and content then that would pass validation. Otherwise if different, that would fail validation.

I read about xml-diff, however what I am interested in is analogous to `Boolean result = xmlDoc.isIdenticalTo(thisXmlDoc)` rather than specific differences between the two documents.

Using Java 8 for this. Does there exist an approach like this?

Answer (score 1):

Install a processor for XQuery 1.0+ or XPath 2.0+ (for example Saxon, or BaseX since that's already there) and run the XPath expression `deep-equal($doc1, $doc2)`.

A warning though: it's quite hard to get this right. There are often niggling differences that you know are irrelevant, but which still make `deep-equal()` return `false`. Saxon offers an alternative `saxon:deep-equal()` that takes options to say what aspects of the document are significant (e.g. whitespace, namespaces, comments) but it can still be a frustrating process. Part of the frustration is simply that `deep-equal()` doesn't tell you what differences it found, and you can spend a long time scratching your head before you work out that it was a tab instead of a space character.